# Failed tests building Dancer2::Plugin::Auth::OAuth from CPAN

Tags: perl, cpan, dancer

I'm trying to build the [Dancer2::Plugin::Auth::OAuth](http://search.cpan.org/~blom/Dancer2-Plugin-Auth-OAuth/lib/Dancer2/Plugin/Auth/OAuth.pm) module from CPAN.  The test fails with:

```
Running Build test
t/01-dancer.t .......... 1/? 
#   Failed test '[github] Session data'
#   at t/01-dancer.t line 238.
#     Structures begin differing at:
#          $got->{user_info}{site_admin} = 'false'
#     $expected->{user_info}{site_admin} = '0'

#   Failed test '[stackexchange] Session data'
#   at t/01-dancer.t line 238.
#     Structures begin differing at:
#          $got->{user_info}{has_more} = 'false'
#     $expected->{user_info}{has_more} = '0'
# Looks like you failed 2 tests of 55.
```

But the [CPAN testers reports](http://www.cpantesters.org/distro/D/Dancer2-Plugin-Auth-OAuth.html#Dancer2-Plugin-Auth-OAuth-0.11) are all green for Linux so it's probably something wrong on my system.

What should I look at?

OS: CentOS 7.3
Perl: 5.16.3 (distro package)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks to me like a bugged test

Perl uses `0`, `"0"`, `""` and `undef` as *false*, and everything else is *true*

This output

```
#          $got->{user_info}{site_admin} = 'false'
#     $expected->{user_info}{site_admin} = '0'
```

says that the hash element was set to the string `false` when the test expected a zero

Since this is only two out of 55 tests that is giving a problem, I would *force* the installation using

```
cpan -f Dancer2::Plugin::Auth::OAuth
```

Comment: I was thinking along those lines... just suprised it didn't get caught by CPAN testers.  I took your advice and did a force... no other errors, guess I'll try using it and see how it goes.